# Singers and genres

Tags: sql

With this Data Base:

```
CREATE TABLE singers (
  idSinger VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
  name STRING,
  age INTEGER,
  country STRING,
  working STRING CHECK working IN ('Yes','No')
);

CREATE TABLE albums (
  idAlbum VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
  name STRING,
  songs INTEGER,
  genre STRING,
  year INTEGER,
  singer STRING REFERENCES cantantes(idCantante)
);


CREATE TABLE songs (
  idSong VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
  name STRING,
  last NUMBER(3,2),
  album VARCHAR REFERENCES albums(idAlbum)
);
```

I want to know how many singers are associated to each genre. I have tried counting albums and then grouping by singers but it doesn't seem to work.

`SELECT COUNT(idSinger), genre FROM albums JOIN singers ON singers.idSinger = albums.singer GROUP BY genre, idSinger;`

Thanks for your help

Comment: maybe this can help: https://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php

Answer (score 1):

Three problems:

1. You are grouping by `idSinger` - only group by non-aggregating columns
2. You are counting the number of *times* singers have sung a genre, not how many *singers* have sung - a singer who has 2 albums in the same genre should only count as one, not two - use `distinct`
3. You are joining - why?

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct idSinger), genre
FROM albums 
GROUP BY genre
```